# How do I install WINE in RHEL 6.3?

Tags: yum, wine

I'm a beginner in Linux and I'm having a problem installing wine 
I'm using RHEL 6.3 and when I use

```
yum install wine
```

it keeps giving me this

```
Blockquote Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.7.3)
Error: Package: wine-cms-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: liblcms.so.1
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libz.so.1
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.8)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.15)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: gnutls(x86-32)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.23)
Error: Package: wine-pulseaudio-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: alsa-plugins-pulseaudio(x86-32)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.2)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.21)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libglib-2.0.so.0
Error: Package: wine-alsa-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libGLU.so.1
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.5.8)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libGL.so.1
Error: Package: wine-ldap-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libldap_r-2.4.so.2
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libX11.so.6
Error: Package: wine-alsa-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libasound.so.2
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libXext.so.6
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libSM.so.6
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.5.7)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libusb-0.1.so.4
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgobject-2.0.so.0
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libICE.so.6
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libexif.so.12
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgphoto2_port.so.0
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.14)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libXrender(x86-32)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.4.30)
Error: Package: wine-alsa-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9.0rc4)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: freetype(x86-32)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgstapp-0.10.so.0
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgthread-2.0.so.0
Error: Package: wine-ldap-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: liblber-2.4.so.2
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libXcursor(x86-32)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgphoto2.so.2
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgmodule-2.0.so.0
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.0)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgstbase-0.10.so.0
```

I'v tried many things I'v installed epel and updated yum

I really could use some help guys thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your machine with RHN and make sure your subscription is current.

Comment: When i try to register it gives me this
Problem registering system:
Error communicating with server. The message was:

Error Class Code: 70
Error Class Info: 
     All available subscriptions for the requested channel have been exhausted.
     Please contact a Red Hat Network Sales associate.
Explanation: 
     An error has occurred while processing your request. If this problem
     persists please enter a bug report at bugzilla.redhat.com.
     If you choose to submit the bug report, please be sure to include
     details of what you were trying to do when this error occurred and

Comment: You let your subscription expire, or you never purchased a subscription. The server is no longer eligible to receive software from Red Hat. Contact Red Hat to renew your subscription.